# Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, view, null

In my Iphone app I have this pb :`Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <UINavigationController:`
 I have a view controller that contains a tableview and I want that if one row is selected an other view controller to be displayed. 
Here is my code :

in RecherchePartenaireViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row==3){
        NSLog(@"RecherchePartenaireDistanceViewController...");

        recherchePartenaireDistanceViewController = [[RecherchePartenaireDistanceViewController alloc]  init];

      self.recherchePartenaireDistanceViewController=recherchePartenaireDistanceViewController.recherchePartenaireViewController;
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:recherchePartenaireDistanceViewController animated:YES];
        [recherchePartenaireDistanceViewController release];
    }
}
```

In RecherchePartenaireDistanceViewController.h :

```
@class RecherchePartenaireViewController;

@interface RecherchePartenaireDistanceViewController : UIViewController {

    RecherchePartenaireViewController *recherchePartenaireViewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet RecherchePartenaireViewController *recherchePartenaireViewController;
@end
```

and in RecherchePartenaireDistanceViewController.m

```
#import "RecherchePartenaireDistanceViewController.h"
#import "RecherchePartenaireViewController.h"

@implementation RecherchePartenaireDistanceViewController


@synthesize recherchePartenaireViewController;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
    [recherchePartenaireViewController release];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

Where is the problem? I really can't see it. Please heeelp....

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [recherchePartenaireViewController release];
    [super dealloc];

}
```

instead of

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
    [recherchePartenaireViewController release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I see what you're doing but I don't understand what you're trying to achieve! You have a ViewController that contains another view controller?

i.e. `RecherchePartenaireDistanceViewController` contains a `RecherchePartenaireViewController`

I assume that as it's an `IBOutlet` you're populating it using a xib file.

The only thing I can think of is that something is going wrong with the creation of your `RecherchePartenaireDistanceViewController` in the xib file.

What do you see in the console if you do this :

```
NSLog(@"controller : %@", recherchePartenaireDistanceViewController);
```

just before adding it to the navigation controller?

PS

What's the purpose of this line?

```
self.recherchePartenaireDistanceViewController=recherchePartenaireDistanceViewController.recherchePartenaireViewController;
```

Answer (score 0):

if RecherchePartenaireDistanceViewController is with xib interface than use following statement while initializing,

```
recherchePartenaireDistanceViewController = [[RecherchePartenaireDistanceViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"RecherchePartenaireDistanceViewController" bundle:nil];
```

than push it to navigation controller.

Comment: If you don't specify a xib file (i.e. just call `init`) then the view controller will automatically look for one with the same name as the class :)

Comment: I'm having still problem ,  nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar
Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
Can't add self as subview, Any help Will be appreciated